# Can a var concatenated to a string be manipulated by reference

Tags: string, perl, reference, concatenation

I need to initialize a string with a fixed text concatenated to a variable like this:

```
   my $id = 0;
   my $text ="This is an example, id: ".$id."\n";
```

Now, in a imaginay loop for 0->9, I want to modify only the `$id` value without changing the fixed text.
I guessed that using references should work like this way

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    my $rid = \$id;
    ${$rid}++;
    print $text;
}
```

Wanted output is

```
This is an example, id: 0
This is an example, id: 1
This is an example, id: 2
```

and so on...but it's not working.

Am I misunderstanding referencing system?

Comment: There's actually a module that allows you to do something like this. Arg! can't remember what it's called. At all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missunderstanding the reference system.

with

```
my $id = 0;
my $text ="This is an example, id: ".$id."\n";
```

The text is concatinated with the value of id at that point, in this case 0. This text loses all connection with the varable $id. Then in the loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    my $rid = \$id;
    ${$rid}++;
    print $text;
}
```

You are incrementing the `$id` variable using `$rid`( which in becomes another name for `$id` at `my $rid = \$id;`  but this will have no affect on the text as it has no reference to the variable `$id`.

The cleanest way of doing what your trying to do is to use a closure

```
my $id = 0;
my $textfunc = sub { return "This is an example, id: ".$id."\n" };
```

then in your loop do

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $id++;
    print $textfunc->();
}
```

Comment: is `print $textfunc();` correct? Because I'm getting the following error at this line: `Not a GLOB reference`

Comment: No, the cleanest way to do this is `print "This is an example, id: $_\n" for 0 .. 9;` Closures?! Just to interpolate a variable into a string? What is the world coming to?!

Comment: @SinanÜnür if the loop is in the same place yes, but the question implied the loop was in some far off part of the program or their would have been no need for references either.

Comment: In that case, don't close on a variable, just pass around a subref. Why not pass an argument to `$textfunc` rather than have invocations of it operate on some variable "in some far off part of the program".

Answer (score 1):

As Sinan pointed out there is an easier way to do this. If you want to keep the `$text` string separate for maintainability and/or reuse, you may also consider using `sprintf`, e.g.:

```
my $id = 0;
my $max_id = 9;
my $text = "This is an example, id: %d\n";

for (my $i = $id; $i < $max_id; $i++) {
    print sprintf($text, $i+1);
}
```

Comment: You can use `printf` in place of `print sprint(...)`.

Comment: Perl is not C. `for my $id (0 .. 9) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about references. Maybe you are thinking thinking of the following C pointer scenario:

```
char text[] = "This is a test xx\n";
char *cursor = text + 15;
*cursor = ' 1';
```

I don't know what thought process can bring about the impression that once you interpolate the contents of `$id` into `my $x = "Test string $id"`, you can change the value of the interpolated string by changing the value of `$id`.

As I said, you really are confused.

Now, if you want a subroutine someplace to be able to format some output without embedding in the subroutine the output format, you can pass as one of the arguments to the subroutine a message formatter as in:

```
my $formatter = sub { sprintf 'The error code is %d', $_[0] };

forbnicate([qw(this that and the other)], $formatter);

sub frobnicate {
    my $args = shift;
    my $formatter = shift;

    # ...

    for my $i (0 .. 9) {
       print $formatter->($i), "\n";
    }

    return;
}
```

This is bound to get tedious, so you can basically have a package of formatters, and let subs use whatever formatters they need:

```
package My::Formatters;

sub error_code {
    my $class = shift;
    return sprintf 'The error code is %d', $_[0];
}
```

In the main script:

```
use My::Formatters;

for my $i (0 .. 9) {
    My::Formatters->error_code($i);
}
```